# <table> vs <div> (yet again)

Tags: html, css, tabular

I generally agree with the idea that web site layouts should be done with <div>s instead of <table>s. However, I have a situation where this does not work - or at least, I have not found any solution.

I have a dynamic site where many customers share the same template (they can pick one from a set of available templates). A template defines the general layout of the site - typically header at the top, two or three columns (menu on the left, primary content in the middle, and sometimes additional content on the right), and footer at the bottom - nothing fancy. The customers have complete control over the contents of the header and the right side content, and significant control over the contents of the menu and main content areas.

The point here is that I do not know what the width of any of the columns will be. The customer may have long or short text for each menu item, they may put small or large images in the right-side column, and the main content can be a free-for-all. I cannot impose too many design restrictions on my customers - they have their own ideas on what the site should look like (some of them get uglier than a MySpace page). There is a 'preferred' width for the site (the main <table> width property) so that when the content is reasonable, the site maintains a nice appearance.

A table based layout just handles this - whatever sizes the columns turn out to be, the table adjusts to fit. <div>s however, do not. If the menu gets a little wider, the other columns drop down below it. If some content is too wide for its container <div>, it extends past the border and interferes with whatever is next to it.

I have played with using Javascript to adjust column widths, but this causes flashing of the layout, where a <table> just renders it without any fuss. I know about the various table-related options for the CSS display property, but since they are not supported widely enough (naughty IE) I can't use them. (And as a snotty aside, the argument that <table>s were never intended to be used for layout, so instead we should use <div>s - and then tell them to behave like <table>s - sounds funny to me.)

So, while I would like to switch to <div>-based layouts for all the usual reasons, I don't believe I can for these templates (or, at least, not until everyone upgrades to IE 10). I am hoping the SO gang can help me find a way to do this.

Comment: Every time I try to switch over from using tables to divs for layout, I end up switching back for exactly these kinds of reasons.  I especially enjoy the article, "Why CSS Should Not Be Used For Layout": http://www.flownet.com/ron/css-rant.html

Comment: I think they both have it place. Table is good to create tabular (grid like) and divs (also its buddy spans) is good for non-tabular as you can float it and other operations. It is just that it is more organize to see your page in grids so table will be here for a long long time. By the way, what is your question.

Comment: @Eli: I disagree. The problem is that too many web designers are control freaks, who want to keep their design fixed *exactly* the way they designed it. The web doesn't work that way. Your design has to work at different resolutions, in different browsers, with screen readers and other media. Any attempt at dictating the *precise* layout of your page is just inherently flawed. So it is not a matter of "can I replace my tables with divs and still get the same result", but rather "replace my tables with divs and let the target device worry about how to display it".

Comment: Eli - thanx for the link - a nicely written explanation of the problem

NawaMan - I agree - and I suppose my question is: "is there a way to handle this with div-based layouts, or are tables actually the only way?" Mostly I just wanted to have a discussion - I have seen a million articles of the "table are evil" variety, but very little which touches on my issue.

Comment: If you're asking the question '<table> vs <div>?' you're doing it wrong. It should be 'meaningless tag-soup vs sematic web-standards'. If you can't get what you want then it's time to face facts and admit that you don't know enough CSS, so either learn more or give it to someone who does.

Comment: Rory - Perhaps you are responding to the title of my question rather than the content. In fact, I would prefer to use a div-based layout, but have a situation where I don't think that I can. I come to SO so that I can "learn more" and don't have to "give it to someone who does". From the tone of your comment, it seems that the solution to my problem is obvious to you. Please share it with the community.

Answer (score 4):

You could make an argument that in your case, the layout essentially *is* a table after all. Often, the point in `<div>`'s is that the precise layout doesn't matter that much. It *has* to be adaptable. If the screen size changes so that your original layout isn't possible, the browser tries to shuffle the elements around to get something that still works. That's one reason why `<div>`'s are usually preferred.

In your case, you want to give that control to the user. And then it is effectively a table, where they get to choose the dimensions and contents of every cell. The fact that it ends up looking like a webpage is almost coincidental.

You're not designing a web page. If you were, you should (and could) use `<div>`'s. You're creating a table, which your users can fill in with the content they like.

I'm sure some purists will disagree with this answer, but ultimately, the rule is not "never use `<table>`, but simply "never use `<table>` for layout". And you're not using it for layout. You're using it to provide a fixed structure for your users to fill data into.

Comment: I think your argument could apply to just about every site on the web. How many web sites are truly built with content blocks that can just be re-arranged any old way? Not too many, I think - most sites seem to have a pretty 'tabular' structure (like mine) even though they are not displaying tabular data. That said - if the content is static, or sizes can be controlled, then I would use a div-based layout (cleaner, smaller, and all the other good reasons).

Comment: Well, few sites are built with blocks that "can just be rearranged any old way". but few sites are *also* built so that a fixed layout works at any old resolution. The problem then becomes how to break it *the least*. A table-based layout breaks horribly if viewed at too small resolution. The horizontal scrolling drives users mad. It also breaks in non-visual renderers, like screen readers. The web isn't static. If it was meant to be pixel-perfect, we'd have used PDF. It is meant to present information in a way meaningful to the *user*, which means the presentation *has* to be flexible.

Comment: I certainly agree that a site needs to adapt as much as possible to the user, but I don't see that (at least in my situation) that a div-based layout would 'fail' more nicely than a table-based layout. I suppose you get more vertical scrolling and less horizontal scrolling, but either way, you have an ugly, difficult-to-use site. I want to research the screen reader issue some more - I have seen confident assertions on both sides (that screen readers can vs. cannot deal with table-based layouts).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this article: [Multi-Column layouts](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlayouts/) but I tend to generally agree. Depending on the nature of the layout of the site, it can be tricky to the point of impractical to use divs for the layout. It's simply a case of some browsers not being where we need them to be to always do that.

Comment: Interesting article - however near the end it says "...these techniques only work with fixed-width sidebars..." which kills the technique for my situation

Answer (score 1):

Working with DIVs sometimes takes huge effort, when trying to tell a complex designs to behave exactly as the designer (or a control freak client) wants.

When ever possible, I use tables instead of divs, this gives me the peace of mind when working on a tightly scheduled project when messing around with different browsers.

ALternatively, when I got the time, I use DIVS as an elegant way of doing things right. just for the fun of it.

Answer (score 0):

Some would argue that you can get the same (or close enough) level of certainty with  and  and an assortment of CSS magic. It just takes a different mindset. For those of us who "grew up" with tables, its different and requires some re-learning. Which we need to do as this is not the same web it once was.

Having said that, I do think that tables have gotten a bit of a bad rap, and I suspect it has a lot to with the newcomers who "grew up" on the developer reaction to table-based design - but without the history, and deeper knowledge of web design, they tend more towards the vapid rants that seem to proliferate and lean on each other. But that's another rant for another day.

I'm going to suggest that this question get closed as its not a question for SO.